# How to prove finite absolute value of expectation for $Z(t)=W(t)^2t$ when $W(t)$ is a standard Wiener Process?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, brownian-motion, absolute-value

The question lies in the title. I am trying to show that $Z(t)$ is a Martingale. The martingale property associated with the filtration I have computed..

I tried using the Hölder's Inequality to prove it, but then I arrive with having to compute the fourth moment of the Wiener process, so I think I have done something wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't it be $W(t)^2/t$ rather than $W(t)^2 t$ ? As is, $\mathbb{E}(Z(t))= t^2$ which is time-dependent, so $Z$ is not a martingale.

Comment: it should be minus t. sorry!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Note for later : your question should be contained in the question body too, not just in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x,t)=tx^2$.
By Ito's lemma you have
$$
df (W_t,t)= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(W_t,t)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(W_t,t)\right)dt +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(W_t,t) dW_t 
$$
The second addendum vanish in mean because Brownian motion are martigales so you only need to estimae the first addendum. Remember that $\mathbb{E}\left[W_t^2\right]=t$. So by applying Fubini you obtain

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[W_t^2 t\right]=2 \int_0^t s ds=t^2
$$
so it is not a martingala

EDIT:
if there is a typo and the process is $W_t^2-t$ you can prove it by using the definition of Brownian motion. In particular, the fact that
$W_t-W_s$ is a Gaussian random variable with law $\mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$.
Because $W_0=0$ this imply:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[W_t^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[W_t^2-2 W_0W_t+W_0\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[(W_t-W_0)^2\right]=t
$$